# How to remove defalult text when using RAF eg(Ad 1 of 1)

Tags: scene, roku, brightscript

I am working on RAF(Roku Advertising Framework) using bright script.
[image: How to remove (Ad 1 of 1]
On above image we seeing (Ad 1 of 1) when playing ads. 
Please give me suggestions to solve this issue, Any help much appreciated.

Comment: This is a bad idea. The UI should convey to users they are watching an ad and hint of how long more they are to suffer. The text "Ad 1 of 3" does that job well. "Get with the program!" already, move the "dfp video" blotch to the right corner if need be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current version of RAF (1.9.6) there is **no way** of doing this.

Comment: Thank you so much  for your reply, Please provide me any reference.

Comment: You can find all the docs on RAF here: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Roku+Advertising+Framework. There are no methods for such type of customization there.

Comment: Interestingly I'm not getting this UI on my case. I need to find what is wrong with my implementation!!

Answer (score 2):

Nas is correct to a certain limit. The Roku checklist will want to have the "Feedback UI" enabled if you're watching ads (this is the "Ad 1 of 1")

Now, it is possible to create your own roVideoPlayer to play the ads. It requires more work to do...

```
'handle this else where (like the construct):
function main
  'm._raf             = Roku_Ads()
  'm._raf.setDebugOutput(true)
  'm._raf.setAdPrefs(false, 2)
  'm._raf.setAdUrl(url)
  'playAds()
end function

function playAds()
  ' sleep for half a second
  sleep(500)

  ' setup some variables we'll be using
  canvas    = createObject("roImageCanvas")

  ' get the ads from the url  
  adPods = m._raf.getAds()

  if adPods <> invalid and adPods.Count() > 0 then
    ' quick display for us to know how many ads we're playing
    print "playing " adPods.Count() " ads"

    ' loop through each ad pod
    for each adPod in adPods
      ' handle any top level logic here

      ' loop through each ad within the adPod now
      for each ad in adPod.ads
        ' default ad rendering by raf: m._raf.showAds(adPods)

        ' start playing the ad
        adVideoPlayer = playVideoContent(ad.streams)

        playingAd = true

        ' custom event loop for the ad video player
        while playingAd
          videoMsg = wait(500, adVideoPlayer.getMessagePort())

          if type(videoMsg) = "roVideoPlayerEvent" then
            if videoMsg.isStreamStarted() then                
              canvas.clearLayer(2) ' clear buffering layer
              canvas.setLayer(1, [{ color: "#00000000", CompositionMode: "Source" }])
              canvas.show()
            else if videoMsg.isPlaybackPosition() then              
              ' loop through all trackers to see if we need to trigger any of them
              for each tracker in ad.tracking
                ' make sure its not triggered first and that the tracker has a "time" property
                if not tracker.triggered and tracker.time <> invalid then
                  print "* ad position: " videoMsg.getIndex() " / " adVideoPlayer.getPlaybackDuration()

                  if (int(videoMsg.getIndex()) + 1) >= int(tracker.time) then
                    print "triggering ad event " tracker.event ", triggered at position " tracker.time
                    m._raf.fireTrackingEvents(ad, {type: tracker.event})
                    tracker.triggered = true
                  end if
                end if
              end for
            end if

            if videoMsg.isStatusMessage() then
              status = videoMsg.getMessage()

              if status = "startup progress" then
                ' handle loading bar or anything else here
              else if status = "start of play" then
                ' we should be playing the video, nuke the buffering layer and set layer 1 to a black background
                canvas.clearLayer(2) ' clear buffering layer
                canvas.setLayer(1, [{ color: "#00000000", CompositionMode: "Source" }])
                canvas.show()
              else
                print "ad status: " status
              end if

              ' roVideoPlayer sends "end of stream" last for all exit conditions
              if status = "playback stopped" or status = "end of playlist" or status = "end of stream"  then
                print "done playing ads"
                playingAd = false
              end if ' end status check
            end if ' end isStatusMessage
          end if ' end type(videoMsg)
        end while

        if type(adVideoPlayer) = "roVideoPlayer" then
          print "stop the ad video player"
          adVideoPlayer.stop()
        end if
      end for
    end for
  else
    print "no ads to play"
  end if
end function
```